# AMD Phenom II X2 555 Black Edition CPU Overheating on Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: 64-bit, overheating, amd-phenom

I was using the Windows 7 32-bit from last year, but switched to the 64-bit about 4 months ago. Since then I have noticed my CPU temp. is on rise. 
It was working fine, but as the start of summer season, It goes to 70*C in just about 20-30 mins. I have shutdown setting in my BIOS for max temp. 70*C.

I have changed and replaced my CPU fan and heatsink, but problem still exists.

What is the max temp for AMD Phenom II and can any suggest what I can do to resolve this heating issue?

Thanks.

Comment: This question may get closed in its current format, I've made a change and I hope to keep it open. If you don't like my change, you can roll it back.

Comment: Your computer overheating has nothing to do with your migration to a 64-bit operating system.  Sounds like you should look at the typical reasons a computer overheats ( dust, old thermal paste ).

Comment: Thanks Dave Rook, I really need to solve this problem, I am unable to operate my system form last couple of weeks.

Comment: How imp. is thermal paste, I think its almost dried up.

Comment: @All, I found the actual reason for this, It was due to dried up Thermal paste. I added new Thermal paste and Replaced the Heat sink and All seems fine from then. 

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You probably shouldn't allow much higher temperatures. 70 is max according to AMD, for what it's worth.

http://products.amd.com/en-us/DesktopCPUDetail.aspx?id=624&f1=&f2=&f3=&f4=&f5=&f6=&f7=&f8=&f9=&f10=&f11=&f12=

I doubt that 64-bit windows is to blame. Even if windows made your CPU run at full load constantly, it still shouldn't go past the thermal limit.

Make sure that:

- The heatsink is attached properly.
- You are using a (decent) amount of thermal grease. The size of a grain of rice usually works well.
- The fan is spinning freely.
- You have decent airflow in the case. Try running without the side panel for a while to see if airflow is an issue.

Comment: How imp. is thermal paste, I think its almost dried up.

Comment: It's fairly important, but there's no need to be fancy. http://www.dansdata.com/goop.htm

Answer (score 0):

Make sure it is not a hardware error - may be your cooler went loose or its thermal grease dried up. Such things always tend to happen after OS reinstall and then you scratch your head a lot. 
If this doesn't help, check if may be you have switched off all powersaving features in BIOS. If you do, CPU would heat as if constantly under 100% load.